# jQuery AJAX on Joomla! works on local but gives error 500 on the server

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, joomla

I've developed a statistics for a Joomla! component which has 3 AJAX calls. The whole app works on local perfect but when I test it on a live server, the AJAX files don't work at all. They return 500 while calling via component or directly.

My local app: `Wamp Server`
The Server: `DirectAdmin`
Live AJAX URLs:

```
http://spaline.pc-games.co.il/administrator/components/com_product/views/reports/funnel.ajax.php?callback=5
```

and

```
http://spaline.pc-games.co.il/administrator/components/com_product/views/reports/callback.php?callback=cart-filling&date=5
```

and

```
http://spaline.pc-games.co.il/administrator/components/com_product/views/reports/filters.php?box_id=5&filter=grey
```

In addition,
Regarding the paths of the AJAX files, I've defined them this way:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

// defining the base path.
if (stristr( $_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], 'win32' )) {
    define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'..\..\..\..\..\..\' ));
} else define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'../../../../../../' ));
    define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

    // including the main joomla files
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE.DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );

    // Creating an app instance
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $app->initialise();
    jimport( 'joomla.user.user' );
    jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );
...
```

I checked the paths and there is no 404 error. The problem is with my AJAX files. I've no idea if the way I've defined the Joomla! header is making this problem or the problem is with the AJAX functions itself or so.

Comment: Why don't you create a component which performs the necessary actions? This way you don't need to worry about copying Joomla! application initialization code and you can focus on your functionality.

Comment: You mean a non-Joomla component? If you mean that, I've to say the project was adding a statistics to an existing Joomla! component and if I wouldn't use AJAX and the way I used, I'd face to many problems. But if I'm wrong about your meaning, I'll be pleased to find out more about your idea.

Comment: I mean a native Joomla component. You path already contains "com_product". I recommend to implement it in a way you can use a url like index.php?option=com_product&view=reports&layout=filter|funnel|callback.

Comment: Ah yes, got it. You're right. That's a better way :-) But the problem was about the path integration on AJAX files not on view.html or default.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the files paths. I figured it out this way:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );

    define( 'JPATH_BASE', realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../../../..' ));

    // including the main joomla files
    require_once ( JPATH_BASE . '/includes/defines.php' );
    require_once (  JPATH_BASE . '/includes/framework.php' );
    require_once (  JPATH_BASE . '/configuration.php' );

    // Creating an app instance
    $app = JFactory::getApplication('site');
    $app->initialise();
    jimport( 'joomla.user.user' );
    jimport( 'joomla.user.helper' );
...
```